# JAVA: Restfull web service not passing parameter correctly

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, digital-signature

I am trying to create a simple rest service, using spring mvc. Everything is working fine except for one method!

I want to pass a signature(using a private key), encoded in Base64 (using bouncy castle encoder) as a parameter so i can validate it in the server side. The problem is, the signature is not getting to the server correctly!

My server method:

```
@RequestMapping("/indirectAcess")
public @ResponseBody byte[] getResource(
        @RequestParam(value="id", required=true) String idString,
        @RequestParam(value="url", required=true) String url, 
        @RequestParam(value="sig", required=true) byte[] sig){

    try{
        int id = Integer.parseInt(idString);
        if(IndirectAccessValidate(id, url, sig)){
            return "HERE IS YOUR RESOURCE".getBytes();
        }
        return null;
    } catch(Exception e){
        return "ERROR".getBytes();
    }

}
```

My client method:

```
private static void indirectAccess(Scanner in){
    System.out.print("URL: ");
    String url = in.nextLine();
    Teste finalUrl = client.generateIndirectAccess(url);
    byte[] response = rest.getForObject(indirect, byte[].class, finalUrl.getId(), finalUrl.getUrl(), finalUrl.getSig());
    System.out.println(new String(response));
}
```

I've tried to debug it and the server is receiving the ID and URL correctly, but not the signature (its just some kind of garbage).

Can anyone please help me? Thank you

Comment: Did you try to use String instead of byte[] for sig ?

Comment: I did tried to use a String but no luck... i also tried to convert a String to byte array like - `finalUrl.getUrl().getbytes()` but still, the server was not getting it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while i solved it!

I still don't know why but, i had to pass the signature as `Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(finalUrl.getSig()`

and decoded it as `Base64.decodeBase64(sig)`

Server

```
    @RequestMapping("/indirectAcess")
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getResource(
            @RequestParam(value="id", required=true) String idString,
            @RequestParam(value="url", required=true) String url, 
            @RequestParam(value="sig", required=true) String sig){

        try{
            int id = Integer.parseInt(idString);
            if(IndirectAccessValidate(id, url, Base64.decodeBase64(sig))){
                return "HERE IS YOUR RESOURCE".getBytes();
            }
            return null;
        } catch(Exception e){
            return "ERROR".getBytes();
        }

    }
```

Client

```
private static void indirectAccess(Scanner in){
    System.out.print("URL: ");
    String url = in.nextLine();
    Teste finalUrl = client.generateIndirectAccess(url);
    byte[] response = rest.getForObject(indirect, byte[].class, finalUrl.getId(), finalUrl.getUrl(), Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(finalUrl.getSig()));
    System.out.println(new String(response));
}
```

I would appreciate if someone could explain me why this happened, because i still can find a reason for... 
Thank you